# CopyAsync method not working in my application

Tags: c#, uwp

I am writing code to copy an mp3 file into the local folder of an application. I am trying to use the CopyAsync method to do this, but a red squiggly line appears underneath this method and I'm unsure of how to fix it. The error specifies that there is no accessible extension method. It then advises if I'm missing an assembly reference or a user directive.

I've found extensive information on this method through Microsoft, so I know it's possible. I'm brand new to building apps in C#, so I am not quite sure how to fix it.

My code is included below:

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Text;

using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Storage;

namespace MusicLibraryTest

{

public static class LibraryHelper

{

    public static async void ChooseMusic()

    {

        //Music Library is opened on user's computer and displays all available mp3 files

        var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker
        {
            ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail,
            SuggestedStartLocation =
        Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.MusicLibrary
        };

        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");

        //File is copied to local folder for use in music library
        var file = picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (file != null)
        {
            await file.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
var file = picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
```

To

```
var file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
```

You're calling an async method that should be awaited.